# В чем разница между кодировками файлов в формате windows и UNIX

Tags: кодировка

В настройках PhpDesigner изменил формат.
[image]

но создает файлы в формате windows. Какая между ними разница?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего это просто формат символов новых строк. В винде новая строка кодируется как \r\n (CRLF), в то время как в никсах это просто \n (LF). Скорее всего, дизайнер определяет текущий формат по содержимому файла, т.е. если там есть CRLF, то он считается за виндовый, и настройки *создания* новых файлов ему не помогут (а вот замена CRLF на просто LF - поможет).